# writing persian text into a text file in the way which could be read in python

Tags: python, string, unicode-string, sys

I have developed a simple program which sends a request to a persian web server and gets the source code of the main page. Then I convert it to string , use `file.open (new_file , 'w')` and paste the string in it.

When i use `print` the string in python idle I can see the right words in persian but the text file which i made in directory is written with strings like `\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb9\n`.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request as ul
import sys

url = 'http://www.uut.ac.ir/'
resp = ul.urlopen(url).read()
string = str(resp)
create_file(filename , string)   # this function creates a text file in desktop
```

I also used:

```
file.open(new_file , 'w' , encoding = 'utf-8')
string = resp.encode('utf-8')
```

But nothing changed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So look at your code:

```
>>> resp = ul.urlopen(url).read()
>>> type(resp)
<class 'bytes'>
```

1. `resp` has the type `bytes`. In the next you have used:

```py
string = str(resp)
```

But you have forgot to set the encoding. The right command is:

```
string = str(resp, encoding="utf-8")
```

Now you get the right string and can write it directly to your file.

2. Your solution 2 is false. You must use `decode` instead of `encode`.

```py
string = resp.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

decode the web site content before write into file

```
import urllib.request as ul
import sys

url = 'http://www.uut.ac.ir/'
resp = ul.urlopen(url).read()

string = str(resp.decode())

f=open("a.txt",'w')
f.write(string)
```